# Adding user details in Office 365

Tags: powershell, office365

I am an Office 365 admin and I want to add users' details like job title, department, company name for all the users using power shell command or EMC. 
How can this be done?

Comment: You might consider posting this question on http://www.serverfault.com to increase the likelihood of getting answers.  That site is devoted to "managing information technology systems in a business environment".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Office 365 uses the Azure AD, so I think you need to set it by using the Azure PowerShell.

[Set-MsolUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194136.aspx)